# how can i add more colors to custom qt-material theme.xml file and call these colors inside the pyqt5 code?

Tags: xml, pyqt5, themes

I have created a new custom theme (.xml) file and added an additional color to it. I am trying to access this color from the python file, what's the best way to do that? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib2xF.png)

Here is where I am trying to access the new text color, but this is not working [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZsgu.png)

Comment: Please don't upload code as images, instead copy it as text and use \``` code here \```

Answer (score 0):

Qt_material provides other options for your personal css template

you can copy any built-in xml file placed in qt_material > themes folder
Paste it and rename it whatever you want.

```
e.g mytemplate.xml
```

Put any color codes without changing the names of parameters and then call it

```
apply_stylesheet(app, theme="mytemplate.xml")
```

Or you can create your own css file and you can overwrite it in the theme by adding your css file as below

```
apply_stylesheet(app, theme="mytemplate.xml" css_file="mycssfile.css")
```

Or you can do your css as below

```
somecss = {

# Button colors
'danger': '#dc3546',
'warning': '#ffc106',
'success': '#17a2b7',

# Font
'font_family': 'Roboto',
}

apply_stylesheet(app, 'light_cyan.xml', invert_secondary=True, extra=somecss)
```